# Can I use C as a scripting language for my engine?

Tags: c, scripting, lua

I have a game engine right now and I'm looking for a scripting language for it. I tried Lua and find it quite good but I want to have my script to look like C or better C++ or look like unreal engine's script would be better.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Why would you want to use a language like C as a scripting language?  Do you really want your users to have to deal with memory management, low-level string handling, etc. etc.?

Comment: (Almost) anything is possible. But you may have to build your own interpreter if your requirements deviate too far from what's already been built by others and made available for you to use.

Comment: relevant link: http://bellard.org/tcc/

Comment: Do you want C, or a C-like syntax? JavaScript looks kind of like C if you squint, and is pretty well established as a scripting language.

Comment: @detly's makes a very good point. Check [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) if you want to embed a very efficient JS interpreter.

Comment: That seems like a pretty superficial reason. Why do you want it to look like C or C++? Is there a better reason than that you just don't like the syntax?

Comment: https://root.cern/cling/

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can :P You can do everything if you want to.

I currently see these three ways:

- Either you write the code yourself to parse the C/C++-Code, which really isn't an easy task
- You use a parser which analyzes and interprets C-Code. [Ch Standard edition](http://www.softintegration.com/products/chstandard/download/) should do the trick as it can be included in own projects as a scripting language.
- Another way would be to create a script which dynamically compiles the user-generated code to a shared library which is dynamically loaded by your engine. Although this wouldn't be  "scripting" anymore.

Comment: The third option would have the advantage of being a lot faster than genuine scripting languages (provided compilation is not done repeatedly).

Comment: The entire reason for a scripting language in games is that it's easy to write code in a scripting engine, and that it can be easily adjusted (preferably at runtime, which saves a lot of debugging time). C/C++ doesn't fit that bill at all.

Comment: @bitmask, Roy T: True. But why are you guys adding this comment to my reply instead of the OP's question?

Comment: Because I don't like answers that only say, "Hey, this is what this other guy said; I'm just repeating it for phony reputation's sake!". It was your answer, not mine -- I'm just trying to help the OP deciding which of your suggestions would fit a given requirement best.

Comment: @bitmask: sry, it shouldn't be any offense, I just wondered. Didn't really get that it actually based on my reply.

Comment: @RoyT.  This is exactly what I'm doing in my code right now.  My "script" compiles in less than 1 second, updates at runtime, has _full_ debugging support out-of-the-box, has complete access to the rest of my codebase for free (if I want it), and is statically typed.  Not only does C fit the bill, it does so better, faster, more easily, and more robustly than any scripting language I've ever used.  I highly recommend this approach to anyone who wants a better scripting system. (The only issue is maintaining static variables between function calls, as those get erased when the code recompiles.)

Answer (score 4):

Check AngelScript, GameMonkey, and there are many others

http://codeplea.com/game-scripting-languages

Or maybe go the hard-way and integrate the CINT C/C++ interpreter (http://root.cern.ch) with the ROOT library. The idea is that you would be interpreting all your .c/.cpp files that you are actively working on, while the rest are compiled (your choice).

For example you are the audio programmer, you would like the rest of the non-audio code to be blazingly fast, while the stuff you are actively working not so, but to have fast iteration - hot-loading, change on the fly, etc.

In addition CINT interpreter has extra dynamic language facilities - you can introspect (reflection) - allowing you to create for example serializers for packing of your game assets, or whatever you might need.

There is also UnderC, and Ch (as being mentioned) and many many others...

Answer (score 2):

[Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/) is language implementation system based on the Lua codebase that exposes various language innards such as the parser ([gg/mlp](http://metalua.luaforge.net/manual004.html)), so allowing you to extend the language or completely change the syntax.  Think of a cross between yacc and a Lispy metacircular interpreter.

It's not quite clear to me what you are after with *look like C or better C++*, but I think this sounds along the right lines and offers a nice balance between implementation ease and flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

There are number of scripting languages with more or less C like syntax.  Others already mentioned ECMAScript, another option would be [s-lang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/), which was designed as a scripting language, is easy to embed, and has a syntax that is pretty close to C.

Comment: ECMAScript is the way to go, seems to me. There are reliable engines available. I don't know V8's license, but if you can use that, you'll be in good shape.

Answer (score 2):

[TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) has a a library allowing for dynamic compilation of C code, and seeing as its pretty fast as a C compiler, its can be used to compile stuff (almost) on-the-fly, there is a really basic example [here](http://z0mbie.daemonlab.org/libtcc.c.txt), however the TCC documentation in the header is way better in explaining stuff.

it also comes with a [better example](http://pastebin.com/h1U6SJW7) of its own showing how to expose symbols to the compiler when using libtcc, this can allow you to sandbox your scripts if you disable certain portions of the compiler (mainly the import of external libraries other than those on a safe list), which is possible as its fully opensource and not *too* complex and it has some basic documents on its internal structure.

Comment: TCC is a great proof of concept, but it was not widely taken up, and it now seems to be abandonware.  It's a shame, but it probably is not a good solution to the asker's problem.

Comment: @CharlesStewart: The TCC mailing list is still active, and so are some of the CVS branches, a new version was release in Feb this year as well. The real point is that it is small, simple to use AND fast.

Comment: Oh, I am glad to hear that.  There was no recent version a few years back, and the old version I had trouble compiling.  I shall take a look again.

Answer (score 1):

Like what like @Charles said use Metalua if you want something easy to implement and have flexibility. If you want a C-like scripting language you can try ECMAScript or any of it supersets(JavaScript, JScript, ActionScript).